# How come my template tag doesn't work in Django Templates?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, templatetags

```
{% gen_aws "hello" %}
```

In my file, I do this:

```py
# I want to add "goodbye" to every word passed to this tag.
@register.tag(name="gen_aws")
def gen_aws(s):
    return s + "goodbye"
```

The `.py` file is fine...I'm including everything fine. I have other template `filters` in there that work fine. But then I added this in that file, and this template tag doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your description of "doesn't work" is not very accurate (to be exact it doesn't exist). But I guess you get an error because the tag is not found.

The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) clearly states that you need a "templatetags" module in your app, with a submodule like "mytags", for example. Then you have to include these tags in each template you want to use them. You can do that with `{% load mytags %}`.

The "mytags" module then contains your "gen_aws" tag.

**EDIT:** The error "gen_aws() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" occurs because normal tags can parse their parameter in a very customized way. Therefore they get the arguments "parser" and "token". In your case, a so-called [simple tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#shortcut-for-simple-tags) should be enough - Django then automatically parses parameters for you and passes them as Python values. So just replace `@register.tag` by `@register.simple_tag`.

Comment: @TIMEX: So then *what exactly* is your problem?

Comment: gen_aws() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: When I change it to this: gen_aws(a, s), I get this error: 'str' object has no attribute 'must_be_first'

Answer (score 7):

Another possible cause of the `"no attribute 'must_be_first'"` error is that you've forgot to inherit from `django.template.Node` in your class. (Since this is pretty much the only Google result for that phrase I thought I'd add this here to save a couple of minutes for the next person.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [@register.simple_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) as shown below instead of [@register.tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-the-tag) whose function cannot get the values but can get the tokens from the template tag and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76246817/register-simple-tag-vs-register-tag-vs-register-inclusion-tag-in-django-templ/76246818#76246818) explaining more about `@register.simple_tag` and `@register.tag`:

```py
# @register.tag(name="gen_aws")
@register.simple_tag(name="gen_aws")
def gen_aws(s):
    return s + "goodbye"
```