# @register.filter vs @register.simple_tag vs @register.tag vs @register.inclusion_tag in Django Templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, python-decorators, templatetags

[The doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) says about [@register.filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.filter) below:

> Custom filters are Python functions that take one or two arguments:
>
> - The value of the variable (input) – not necessarily a string.
> - The value of the argument – this can have a default value, or be left out altogether.

And, [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) says about [@register.simple_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag) below:

> This function, which is a method of django.template.Library, takes a
> function that accepts any number of arguments, wraps it in a render
> function and the other necessary bits mentioned above and registers it
> with the template system.

And, [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-the-tag) only says about `@register.tag` below:

> Finally, register the tag with your module’s Library instance, as
> explained in writing custom template tags above.

And, [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) says about [@register.inclusion_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.inclusion_tag) below:

> Another common type of template tag is the type that displays some
> data by rendering another template. For example, Django’s admin
> interface uses custom template tags to display the buttons along the
> bottom of the “add/change” form pages. Those buttons always look the
> same, but the link targets change depending on the object being edited
> – so they’re a perfect case for using a small template that is filled
> with details from the current object.

But, I don't understand what they are like so what is the difference between `@register.filter` `@register.simple_tag`, `@register.tag` and `@register.inclusion_tag` in Django Templates?

Answer (score 0):

[@register.filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters):

- can return data to Django Templates.
- 's function can get the values from the template tag.
- 's function must have one or two parameters. *If it has zero or more than two parameters, there is error.
- cannot have `takes_context` parameter.
- doesn't work with `as` argument.

[@register.simple_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

- can return data to Django Templates.
- 's function can get the values from the template tag.
- can have `takes_context` parameter.
- 's function must have `context` as the 1st parameter if `takes_context=True` is set to `@register.simple_tag` otherwise there is an error. *The 1st parameter name must be `context` otherwise there is an error.
- works with `as` argument.

[@register.tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-the-tag):

- should return a `str` type value from a `Node` class based object to Django Templates otherwise there is an error.
- 's function can get the tokens from the template tag.
- cannot have `takes_context` parameter.
- 's function must have `parser` as the 1st parameter and `token` as the 2nd parameter in convention (other names are fine) otherwise there is an error.
- doesn't work with `as` argument.

[@register.inclusion_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags):

- can return data to other Django Templates but not to the same Django Templates because there is an error.
- 's function can get the values from the template tag.
- can have `takes_context` parameter.
- 's function must have `context` as the 1st parameter if `takes_context=True` is set to `@register.inclusion_tag` otherwise there is an error. *The 1st parameter name must be `context` otherwise there is an error.
- doesn't work with `as` argument.

## <@register.filter>

For example, return a dictionary to `index.html` from `person_view()` as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def person_view(request):                # Dictionary
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'name':'John', 'age': 36})
```

Then, pass `name` to `person_filter()` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{% load custom_tags %}

{{ name | person }}
```

Then, return `name` from `person_filter()` to `index.html` as shown below:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.filter(name="person")
def person_filter(name):
    return name
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
John
```

Next, pass `name` and `age` to `person_filter()` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{% load custom_tags %}

{{ name | person:age }}
```

Then, return `name` and `age` from `person_filter()` to `index.html` as shown below:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.filter(name="person")
def person_filter(name, age):
    return f'{name} {age}'
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
John 36
```

## <@register.simple_tag>

For example, return a dictionary to `index.html` from `person_view()` as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def person_view(request):                # Dictionary
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'name':'John', 'age': 36})
```

Then, pass `name`, `age` and `"Good Person"` to `person_tag()` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{% load custom_tags %}

{% person name age "Good Person" %}
```

Then, return `name`, `age` and `extra_info` from `person_tag()` to `index.html` as shown below:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.simple_tag(name="person")
def person_tag(name, age, extra_info):
    return f'{name} {age} {extra_info}'
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
John 36 Good Person
```

Next, set `takes_context=True` to `@register.simple_tag`, then for `person_tag()`, we don't need `name` and `age` parameters, then must put `context` which is a dictionary as the 1st parameter as shown below. *If the 1st parameter name is not `context`, there is an error:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"
                                    # Here
@register.simple_tag(name="person", takes_context=True)
def person_tag(context, extra_info):
    return f"{context['name']} {context['age']} {extra_info}"
```

Then, pass only `"Good Person"` to `person_tag()` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{% person "Good Person" %}
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
John 36 Good Person
```

Actually, you can still pass `name` and `age` from `index.html` to `person_tag()` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{% person name age "Good Person" %}
```

But, `person_tag()` needs 2 more parameters as shown below. *Other names are fine for `name` and `age` parameters:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

@register.simple_tag(name="person", takes_context=True)
def person_tag(context, name, age, extra_info):
    # ...                 ↑    ↑
```

Next, store the return values from `person_tag()` to `person_info` with `as` argument, then display it as shown below. *The tag with `as` argument is not displayed:

```
# "index.html"

{% person "Good Person" as person_info %}
{{ person_info }}
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
John 36 Good Person
```

Lastly in `person_tag()`, set `context['extra_info']`, then return an empty string to `index.html` as shown below:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

@register.simple_tag(name="person", takes_context=True)
def person_tag(context, extra_info):
    context['extra_info'] = extra_info
    return ""
```

Then, display `name`, `age` and `extra_info` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{% person "Good Person" %}
{{ name }} {{ age }} {{ extra_info }}
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
John 36 Good Person
```

## <@register.tag>

For example, return a dictionary to `index.html` from `person_view()` as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def person_view(request):                # Dictionary
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'name':'John', 'age': 36})
```

Then, pass `name`, `age` and `"Good Person"` to `person_tag()` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{% load custom_tags %}

{% person name age "Good Person" %}
```

Then from `person_tag()`, return `PersonNode()` which returns 4 tokens from `render()` to `index.html` as shown below. *The 1st token is the tag name `person` and the 2nd token is `name` and the 3rd token is `age` and the 4th token is `"Good Person"` and `@register.tag` cannot have `takes_context` parameter and `@register.tag`'s function must have `parser` as the 1st parameter and `token` as the 2nd parameter in convention (other names are fine) otherwise there is an error:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

from django.template import Library, Node

register = Library()

@register.tag(name="person")
def person_tag(parser, token):
    token0, token1, token2, token3 = token.split_contents()
    return PersonNode(token0, token1, token2, token3)

class PersonNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, token0, token1, token2, token3):
        self.token0 = token0
        self.token1 = token1
        self.token2 = token2
        self.token3 = token3

    def render(self, context):
        return f'{self.token0} {self.token1} {self.token2} {self.token3}'
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
person name age "Good Person"
```

And, this code below returns the 1st token, the actual `name` and `age` values got by the 2nd and 3rd tokens respectively and the 4th token without double quotes. *`template.Variable("key.dot.notation").resolve(dict)` can get the value from a dictionary with a key dot notation and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183252/what-does-resolve-variable-do-in-django-template-variable/76244755#76244755) explaining `template.Variable("key.dot.notation").resolve(dict)`:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

@register.tag(name="person")
def person_tag(parser, token):
    token0, token1, token2, token3 = token.split_contents()
    return PersonNode(token0, token1, token2, token3)

class PersonNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, token0, token1, token2, token3):
        self.token0 = token0
        self.token1 = token1
        self.token2 = token2
        self.token3 = token3

    def render(self, context):
        name = template.Variable(self.token1).resolve(context)
        age = template.Variable(self.token2).resolve(context)
        extra_info = self.token3.replace('"', '')
        return f'{self.token0} {name} {age} {extra_info}'
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
person John 36 Good Person
```

And, this code below returns `name` and `age` values from `context` and `Good Person`:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

@register.tag(name="person")
def person_tag(parser, token):
    token0, token1, token2, token3 = token.split_contents()
    return PersonNode()

class PersonNode(Node):
    def render(self, context):
        return f"{context['name']} {context['age']} Good Person"
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
John 36 Good Person
```

And in `render()`, set `context['extra_info']`, then return an empty string to `index.html` as shown below:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

@register.tag(name="person")
def person_tag(parser, token):
    return PersonNode()

class PersonNode(Node):
    def render(self, context):
        context['extra_info'] = "Good Person"
        return ""
```

Then, display `name`, `age` and `extra_info` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{% person %}
{{ name }} {{ age }} {{ extra_info }}
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
John 36 Good Person
```

In addition, we can create a comment tag to comment words with `parser` parameter and `@register.tag` as shown below:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

@register.tag(name='comm')
def comment_tag(parser, token):
    parser.skip_past('endcomm')
    return CommentNode()

class CommentNode(Node):
    def render(self, context):
        return ""
```

Then, surround the words with the comment tag `{% comm %}` and `{% endcomm %}` not to display the words as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{% comm %}This is a comment.{% endcomm %}
```

## <@register.inclusion_tag>

For example, return a dictionary to `index.html` from `person_view()` as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def person_view(request):                # Dictionary
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'name':'John', 'age': 36})
```

Then, pass `name`, `age` and `"Good Person"` to `person_tag()` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{% load custom_tags %}

{% person name age "Good Person" %}
```

Then, return a dictionary from `person_tag()` to `result.html` as shown below:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.inclusion_tag(name='person', filename='result.html')
def person_tag(name, age, extra_info):
    return {'n': name, 'a': age, 'ei': extra_info} # Dictionary
```

Then, display `n`, `a` and `ei` in `result.html` as shown below:

```
# "result.html"

{{ n }} {{ a }} {{ ei }}
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
John 36 Good Person
```

Be careful, `name`, `age` and `extra_info` below cannot be displayed in `result.html` because they are not returned from `person_tag()` to `result.html`:

```
# "result.html"

{{ name }} {{ age }} {{ extra_info }}
```

Next, set `takes_context=True` to `@register.inclusion_tag`, then for `person_tag()`, we don't need `name` and `age` parameters, then must put `context` which is a dictionary as the 1st parameter, then set `context['extra_info']` as shown below. *If the 1st parameter name is not `context`, there is an error:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

@register.inclusion_tag(
    name='person', 
    filename='result.html', 
    takes_context=True
)
def person_tag(context, extra_info):
    context['extra_info'] = extra_info
    return context
```

Then, pass only `"Good Person"` to `person_tag()` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{% person "Good Person" %}
```

Then, display `name`, `age` and `extra_info` in `result.html` as shown below:

```
# "result.html"

{{ name }} {{ age }} {{ extra_info }}
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
John 36 Good Person
```

Actually, you can still pass `name` and `age` from `index.html` to `person_tag()` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{% person name age "Good Person" %}
```

But, `person_tag()` needs 2 more parameters as shown below. *Other names are fine for `name` and `age` parameters:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

@register.inclusion_tag(
    name='person', 
    filename='result.html', 
    takes_context=True
)
def person_tag(context, name, age, extra_info):
    # ...                 ↑    ↑
```

Lastly, return an empty dictionary from `person_tag()` to `result.html` as shown below:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

@register.inclusion_tag(
    name='person', 
    filename='result.html', 
    takes_context=True
)
def person_tag(context, extra_info):
    context['extra_info'] = extra_info
    return {} # Dictionary
```

Then, display `name`, `age` and `extra_info` in `index.html` as shown below:

```
# "index.html"

{% person "Good Person" %}
{{ name }} {{ age }} {{ extra_info }}
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
John 36 Good Person
```